# Javascript - Change element's src in specified element

Tags: javascript, html, src

In html I have a lot od DIVs with names(yes, names, not IDs) respectively p001, p002, p003... which are like this:

```
<div id="pole" name="p001"><img src=""></div>
<div id="pole" name="p002"><img src=""></div>
<div id="pole" name="p003"><img src=""></div>
```

etc...

In Javascript I have defined variable called 'pos' which contains a number, for now: "284"
and a function which should change img src to "player.png". 
I tried 2 ways and none of these work:

```
document.getElementsByName('p'+pos).innerHTML='<img src="player.png">';
```

and

```
document.getElementsByName('p'+pos).getElementsByTagName("img").src="player.png";
```

How to change img src which is in specified DIV?

Comment: Your div's must have different ids if you want your html to be valid, and if you want to avoid javascript conflicts.

Comment: `div` elements don't define a `"name"` attribute. Your code will fail in at least IE8 and lower when fetching `div` elements using `getElementsByName`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns a list of elements, not a single element, so try:

```
document.getElementsByName('p'+pos)[0].
    getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src="player.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the all "img" tags in html code. And then you can change the element's src in body or specified element.

```
images = document.querySelectorAll("#content_image img");
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I think you should switch `name` and `id` attributes on your `div` tags. You CANNOT have multiple elements with the same id but you can have multiple elements with the same name.

```
<div name="pole" id="p001"><img src=""></div>
<div name="pole" id="p002"><img src=""></div>
<div name="pole" id="p003"><img src=""></div>
```

To solve your problem you can use the `firstChild` property of DOM if the `img` will always be the first child of your div tag.

```
document.getElementById('p'+pos).firstChild.src="player.png";
```

Comment: 'name' is not a valid attribute for a div.  'name' should rather be 'class' here.